# Cloudstack virtual machines can't communicate with virtual routers when they are on different hosts

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, kvm-virtualization, cloudstack

I'm using Cloudstack 2.2.14 on a Ubuntu 10.04 set of hosts, and I have a problem on my setup.

I have two hosts running. When a virtual router is created on host 1 and a virtual machine using that virtual router is created on host 2, or vice versa, I have no connectivity at all on the virtual machine.

First of all, I have to setup the network manually on that virtual machine -usually DHCP is working, but not here-. Then, I can't ping to the virtual router from the virtual machine or vice versa.

When both virtual router and virtual machine are created on the same host, everything works!

Maybe those packages are being filtered somehow? I have no clue on how to proceed. Both hosts can communicate directly outside the virtualization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not help my karma, but here goes:

After CloudStack became an Apache Foundation Incubator project, the bulk of the orginal development team started reading and answering questions on the cloudstack-users@incubator.apache.org email list.

AFAIK, this includes previous versions of CloudStack such as your 2.2.14.

You can subscribe by sending an email to cloudstack-users-subscribe@incubator.apache.org

There is also an archive here [cloudstack-users@incubator.apache.org](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cloudstack-users/)

Comment: Thank you. I think this solves my problem, since I know now how to keep going. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you are using VLAN isolation but don't have the VLANs configured correctly on your switch.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I wasn't able to get much information from the comments in the post, however it does seem like the issue was resolved. I am wondering if someone can direct to some resources on how to diagnose and resolve the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/546985)